# Java: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I'm beginning to do exercises with simply reading in a data file.  When I run the program, the data file gets read and what not, but for some reason I still get a "NoSuchElementException" and my output is not formatted the way it is supposed to be.  Here is what is going on:

I created a simple data file that looks like this:

```
Barry Burd
Author
5000.00
Harriet Ritter
Captain
7000.00
Ryan Christman
CEO
10000.00
```

After that I wrote a simple "getter" and "setter" program (code is below).

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

  //This class defines what it means to be an employee

public class Employee {

  private String name;
  private String jobTitle;

  public void setName(String nameIn) {
    name = nameIn;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleIn) {
    jobTitle = jobTitleIn;
  }

  public String getJobTitle() {
    return jobTitle;
  }

  /*The following method provides the method for writing a paycheck*/

  public void cutCheck(double amountPaid)   {
    out.printf("Pay to the order of %s ", name);
    out.printf("(%s) ***$", jobTitle);
    out.printf("%,.2f\n", amountPaid);
  }

}
```

Easy enough.  **Then** I wrote the program that actually uses this stuff (code below).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DoPayroll {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("EmployeeInfo.txt"));

    for (int empNum = 1; empNum <= 3; empNum++) {
      payOneEmployee(diskScanner);
    }
  }

  static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner) {
    Employee anEmployee = new Employee();

    anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine());
    anEmployee.setJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine());
    anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble());
    aScanner.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Pay to the order of Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at DoPayroll.payOneEmployee(DoPayroll.java:25)
    at DoPayroll.main(DoPayroll.java:14)
 Barry Burd ( Author) ***$5,000.00
Pay to the order of  Harriet Ritter ( Captain) ***$7,000.00
Pay to the order of  Ryan Christman ( CEO) ***$10,000.00
```

**EDIT**  I found the problem but I don't understand it lol.  Apparently, I had to add a blank line to the end of the data file....why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found the problem but I don't understand it lol. Apparently, I had to add a blank line to the end of the data file....why??

Because you are telling the `Scanner` that there will be a carriage return after the salary in the input file. However, for the last entry, there was no carriage return and so it determined that you had made a programming error and threw an unchecked exception.

You could solve the problem in your code like so:

```
static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner) {
    Employee anEmployee = new Employee();

    anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine());
    anEmployee.setJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine());
    anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble());
    if (aScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        aScanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `payOneEmployee()` you call `aScanner.nextLine()` at the end.  This includes the last time you call it (when `empNum` equals 3 in your `for` loop).  When there were no more new lines (`\n`) in the file and you still called `nextLine()`, you received a `NoSuchElementException` because... well... there was no such element.  This is because the last element in the file is a `0` character.

In order to avoid this in the future, you can add a simple checker.  The `java.util.Scanner` has a `hasNextLine()` already implemented for you.  Thus, you can simply change

```
aScanner.nextLine();
```

... to ...

```
if(aScanner.hasNextLine()) aScanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think it reached the end of the file.  You should add a while loop:

```
while(aScanner.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

This prevents the Scanner from going past the end of the file.

Comment: This is actually a misleading solution.  `hasNext()` will return true as long as there are any non-whitespace characters left to be read by the Scanner.  This may or may not end in a carriage return.  If it doesn't, the code will still enter the `while` loop and the Exception will still be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your file ended with the character '0', while `aScanner.nextLine()` tried to consume a newline character ('\n').

Now, the interesting thing here is where the exception popped up. It seems to be in the middle of the first `cutCheck()` printing. My guess here is that it has to do with IO buffering and asynchronicity of the output streams. `out.printf()` is stdout, while the error message is coming on stderr, so that could explain the odd behavior there.

If you put a `Thread.sleep()` in your for-loop, that might clear up the printing issue (although that's obviously just a curiosity, and not a fix to your code or anything like that).

Comment: Definitely strange that the error was in the middle of the output.

Comment: try adding the Thread.sleep() check. I think I've seen that sort of thing before, and it can definitely make parsing debug output confusing

Answer (score 0):

You should call hasNextLine before calling aScanner.nextLine().
You're trying to read a line where there isn't one, at the end of the file.