# How do I make my own methods in java?

Tags: java, methods

I've been reading Java for Dummies, a beginner java programming book by Barry Burd, it was going great until i got to the "creating your own methods" part. I don't quite understand it, or actually, i don't understand it at all. I found this example in the book. Can you please explain what this program does, and everything in the source code? I would really like to know.

(Note: The following lines are actual code!)

---

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;

    public void setName(String nameIn) {
        name = nameIn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleIn) {
        jobTitle = jobTitleIn;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid) {
        out printf("Pay to the order of %s ", name);
        out.printf(""(% ***$", jobTitle);
        out.printf("%,.2f\n", amountPaid);
    }

}
```

---

Final result (When successfully compiling and then running the program):

---

```
Pay to the order of Barry Bird (CEO) ***$5,000.00
Pay to the order of Harriet Ritter (Captain) ****$7,000.00
Pay to the order of Your Name Here (Honorary Exec of the Day) ***$10,000.00
```

---

At least, Barry Burd is assuming this to happen, but it doesn't. I can't compile it without errors.

The best answer would be a correction of the source code above, with some comments added, but still, any response would be highly appreciated, unfortunately, i don't check my Stack Overflow account often, so, there might be no Top Answer.

Comment: Which part are you confused about? We like to help here and prefer specific questions which we can answer. For example, you say you can't compile without errors. What errors do you get? This is something specific with which we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: This code lacks the method `main()` - so better take care of it before anything else...

Comment: If that book doesn't mention `public static void main(String[] args)` anywhere ... get a new book.

Comment: "I don't check my StackOverflow account often" doesn't inspire people to help.  You are clearly going to check back to see the answer to your question.  Also, in the future, it helps to post the compiler errors.

Comment: Cmon guys give him a break starting out wasn't easy for anyone. Soon as I get home I'll help you out line by line dw.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548956/java-nosuchelementexception

Comment: @Dangerosking If that was directed at me, I was trying to provide advice on posting so it doesn't get downvoted.  It is important to learn how to ask for help (anywhere requires compiler errors) not just learn Java.  I didn't downvote and I provided an answer.

Comment: @Alexander Mladenovic This was gonna be my answer before they closed the question, check if out if you are still having trouble [http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2dc7](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2dc7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
package by.dev.madhead.demo;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;

    public void setName(String nameIn) {
        name = nameIn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleIn) {
        jobTitle = jobTitleIn;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid) {
        out.printf("Pay to the order of %s ", name);
        out.printf("(%s)", jobTitle);
        out.printf(" ***$%,.2f\n", amountPaid);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee e = new Employee();

        e.setName("Drake");
        e.setJobTitle("Programmer");

        e.cutCheck(57005.12);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have two quotes in a row here which causes it to not compile:

```
out.printf(""(% ***$", jobTitle);
```

and you are missing a dot after "out" here:

```
out printf
```

The code is a Java class with getters and setters.  And a print method using Java 5.  (If you are on a really old version of Java, that could be another reason it doesn't compile.)  Which is a style where you specify the format of values you output.

IF you are still having trouble, post the actual compiler error.  And all the code.  This class is obviously called by another.